# print url in iframe in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, lti

I have button that open lti tool in new tab and I want to open it in iframe in the same page

here is the code

```
$launch_url = "https://lti.tools/test/tp.php";
$key = "12345";
$secret = "secret";

$launch_data = array(
    "user_id" => "292832126",
    "roles" => "Instructor",
    "resource_link_id" => "120988f929-274612",
    "resource_link_title" => "Weekly Blog",
    "resource_link_description" => "A weekly blog.",
    "lis_person_name_full" => "Jane Q. Public",
    "lis_person_name_family" => "Public",
    "lis_person_name_given" => "Given",
    "lis_person_contact_email_primary" => "user@school.edu",
    "lis_person_sourcedid" => "school.edu:user",
    "context_id" => "456434513",
    "context_title" => "Design of Personal Environments",
    "context_label" => "SI182",
    "tool_consumer_instance_guid" => "lmsng.school.edu",
    "tool_consumer_instance_description" => "University of School (LMSng)"
);

#
# END OF CONFIGURATION SECTION
# ------------------------------

$now = new DateTime();

$launch_data["lti_version"] = "LTI-1p0";
$launch_data["lti_message_type"] = "basic-lti-launch-request";

# Basic LTI uses OAuth to sign requests
# OAuth Core 1.0 spec: http://oauth.net/core/1.0/

$launch_data["oauth_callback"] = "about:blank";
$launch_data["oauth_consumer_key"] = $key;
$launch_data["oauth_version"] = "1.0";
$launch_data["oauth_nonce"] = uniqid('', true);
$launch_data["oauth_timestamp"] = $now->getTimestamp();
$launch_data["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1";

# In OAuth, request parameters must be sorted by name
$launch_data_keys = array_keys($launch_data);
sort($launch_data_keys);

$launch_params = array();
foreach ($launch_data_keys as $key) {
  array_push($launch_params, $key . "=" . rawurlencode($launch_data[$key]));
}

$base_string = "POST&" . urlencode($launch_url) . "&" . rawurlencode(implode("&", $launch_params));
$secret = urlencode($secret) . "&";
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $secret, true));

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<!-- <body onload="document.ltiLaunchForm.submit();"> -->
<body>
<form id="ltiLaunchForm" name="ltiLaunchForm" method="POST" action="<?php printf($launch_url); ?>">
<?php foreach ($launch_data as $k => $v ) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $k ?>" value="<?php echo $v ?>">
<?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value="<?php echo $signature ?>">
    <button type="submit">Launch</button>
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code always gives me error "HTTP 401 Unauthorized". With my LTI credentials. Any help?